# Trying to display a list of typographic glyphs using html/javascript

Tags: javascript, html, character-encoding, typography

Alright y'all. I am attempting to write a bit of code that places typographic glyphs onto an html page. Glyphs like: &amp (ampersand) and &#165 (yen). I am using a simple for loop to create the numbers 160-255 (numbers that associate with a number of glyphs) and prepending "&#". This i believe creates a string "&#xxx" that is then enclosed in

and added to document.body.

Problem is, all i get is a list of printed strings &#160 - &#255 in the browser. Any thoughts on formatting this differently? I was thinking it could be an encoding error?

```
var p = null;

// make <p> tags and insert string "&#"+i, where i comes from for loop. //


function makeP(glyphNum){


    var gNum = glyphNum.toString();
    p = document.createElement("p");
    var pGlyph = document.createTextNode("&#"+gNum);
    var string = pGlyph.toString();

    p.appendChild(pGlyph);
    //console.log(p);
    document.body.appendChild(p);


}


//create nums for glyphs//


for(var i = 160;i <= 255; i++)
{

    makeP(i);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`document.createTextNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createTextNode) does not parse HTML entities. Instead, set the `innerHTML` property. Note that a numeric HTML entity has to be prefixed by `&#`, and postfixed by a semicolon (`;`).

```
function makeP(glyphNum){
    var p = document.createElement("p");
    p.innerHTML = "&#" + glyphNum + ";";
    document.body.appendChild(p);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to use `String.fromCharCode()` to create content by character code.  [Here is a jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/b9u68/1/)

```
$('p').append((function() {
    var i, s = [];
    for (i = 32; i < 1000; ++i)
        s[i] = String.fromCharCode(i);
    return s.join('');
})());
```